# Removing all html tags in a page besides <a> tags with ES6 Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I desire removing all html tags in a the `#bodyContent` `div` id of a page, besides `<a>` tags, with ES6 Javascript (no jQuery).

The page is a quite long Wikipedia article that shows large amount of text of `p`, `span`, as well as `img`, among others.

Inside the `p` and `span`, there are many `a` tags. Actually, about 99.9% of the `p` tags include at least 1 `a` tag.

Removing all `p` tags that doesn't have an `a` inside them with the following code is ineffective because only about 0.1% of the text is removed:

```
for (const text of document.querySelectorAll("p")) {
    if (!text.querySelector("a")) {
        text.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

I need a solution that will erase everything in the `#bodyContent` `div` of the page, which isn't `a` tags.

The end product should be a Wiki webpage filled only with `a` links.

Comment: It would be much easier to do `querySelectorAll("a")` and move them to your desired target area, then disposing the origin element.

Comment: What do you want to happen to the text, both within, between and outside of the `<a>` elements?

Comment: The text inside the `<a>` tags should stay as is. Everything outside them should vanish, in this page.

Comment: @Bergi, where will you show it? In some new element?, like with createElement() and then document.write the variable with the `a` tags into this new element?

Comment: In some new element or in the old one - have a look at my answer below. No, don't use `document.write`.

Comment: About 2 seconds before your comment I accepted your answer which worked. The only thing I think I miss is why we need the remove child for the first child.

Comment: That's the standard method to empty an element - remove the first child again and again until there are no more.

Comment: Oh, yes, as part of the while so it's time and again. I am not used to this innovative (I guess) way of writing loops, without brackets, but will do! I've learned much. Would have upvoted if I could but miss 3 points. Ben.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just remove all the content, and then put the links back in:

```
const el = document.querySelector("div#bodyContent");
const links = el.querySelectorAll("a");
while (el.hasChildNodes())
    el.removeChild(el.firstChild);
for (const link of links)
    el.appendChild(link);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just select all of the `a` elements from the `p` element and replace the contents with just the `a` elements. Something like:

```
const content = document.querySelector('#bodyContent');
let links = content.querySelectorAll('a');
content.innerHtml = '';
links.foreach(a => {
    content.appendChild(a);
});
```